# Solar cell input for LTspice

Tags: voltage, ltspice, pspice, solar-charge-controller, mppt

I am trying to send a solar input into the LT8390 in LTspice. I am having trouble finding example circuits in LTspice that I can implement. Any direction or LTspice model files would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: A current source into a (stack of) diode(s)?

Comment: You mean a model for a solar panel or an [example circuit for the LT8390](https://www.analog.com/media/en/simulation-models/LTspice-demo-circuits/LT8390_DC2431A.asc)?  Your post is incredibly unclear, and doesn't even really ask a question.

Comment: Have you tried the test schematic that comes with the symbol? It just uses a simple voltage source, probably because modelling a particular solar cell is not needed. If unsure, press `F2`, type `8390`, then click on the `Open this macromodel's test fixture` button when the desired component is selected.

Comment: i want to know how to model a solar panel input into the circuit not just a voltage source

Comment: @Matthew-Davis: You should edit your question to include that; it is unclear as it stands.